# Unable to read session data

Tags: php, session

Below is a stripped down version of my code.

I set the session in the `search` function, and print it out to check its set. The print our works.

I then try and read the session in `search_results` and the error below is shown:

> Undefined index: members_search

I can't for the life of me work out what i'm doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php 

session_start();

class Cdwd_members {

    public function search() 
    {
        $results = '.........'

        $_SESSION['members_search'] = $results;

        print_r($_SESSION['members_search']);
    }   

    public function search_results() 
    {   
        print_r($_SESSION['members_search']);
    }

}
```

Comment: You remove session_start(); and paste the session_start(); in top php page

Comment: End your statements? You are missing semi-colons.

Comment: can you show code of how you are using your class?

Comment: Did you try to print session inside the class before using like- print_r($_SESSION)?

Comment: Please add the code that shows where you use the `search` method. i.e. `$cdwdMembers->search();`.

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` should be put at the top of your script, not in every method.

Put that just after the `<?php` tag.

Comment: Thank you. I have done this, but the same error is displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. `session_start();` shlould be at the top of your page

```
 <?php 
    session_start();
    class Cdwd_members {

        public function search() 
        {
            $results = 'my';        

            $_SESSION['members_search'] = $results;

            print_r($_SESSION['members_search']);
        }   

        public function search_results() 
        {  
            print_r($_SESSION['members_search']);
        }

    }
    $n = new Cdwd_members;
    $n->search();
   $n->search_results();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to place

> start_session

before including the class, or just place it as the first thing what your code will do.

You can also use a constructor if this class is the only place where you are gong to use sessions. A constructor is the first thing a class do automatically when instance is created.

```
function __construct(){
  session_start();
}
```

[Constructor & destructors PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Answer (score 0):

I don't do much OOP but you can try this and see if it works. In `function search()`, instead of `print_r($_SESSION['members_search'])`, try instead `return $_SESSION['members_search']` and then in `function search_results()`, replace the `print_r` with this `print_r(search());`

Answer (score 0):

```
$n = new Cdwd_members;
$n->search_results();
```

You session stored when search method called, maybe you should call 'search' before 'search_results' ?

Answer (score 0):

1. If the ; is missing on line 9 in your code then add it.
2. Make sure that you call function search() before calling search_results(). Or you can call search_results() inside of search() to set the session.